# Git, отменить слияние веток в удаленном репо

Tags: git, git-push, git-merge

Смерджил ствол в свою ветку для апдейта, проверить изменения забыл, понадеялся на то что правильно разрешил все конфликты, поэтому сразу запушил. Никаких коммитов после мерджа и до пуша в своей ветке не делал. Сейчас зашел и понял, что нужно отменить слияние как локально, так и в origin. Не знаю как это сделать.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: git reset с какой нибудь опцией

Comment: **reset** на сервере нельзя @Эникейщик ,а **revert** последний коммит можно спокойно.

Comment: Переместите свои локальные ветки на исходные позиции до слияния, сделайте force push на уделенный репозиторий.

Comment: @user7860670 первая часть не нужна. Просто надо указать правильный хеш для локального репо и сделать force push.